# Problema of difference between DevC + + and gcc

Tags: c, gcc, dev-c++

In gcc, on linux, I don't have a problem using this operation:

```
s->voti->next
```

but in DevC++, on windows, it makes segmentation fault :(

Why? What am I doing wrong? :(

Find the complete code [here](http://nopaste.me/paste/742398834510e1e98d0ee7)

- **line 82** ( **cur=cur->next** should be equal to **s->voti = s->voti->next** )

Comment: Please everyone be patient this is the OP's first question on SoF before downvoting or closing please take your time to propose how to improve the question.

Comment: It is generally better to isolate only a small fraction of the code enough to isolate the problem so that you get better answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow maintains questions indefinitely for the benefit of the community.  Linking to code in a temporary off-site location is unhelpful since it will render this question less useful when the link expires, especially as it appears that this code is not *exactly* the code in question (w.r.t. line 82?).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good question, but the function call at line 187 definitely didn't initialize `new_node->voti` before it is passed to `insertMateria`.

Answer (score 1):

Dev-C++ *is not* a compiler.  It is an IDE.  It is packaged with MinGW GCC (i.e. it *is* GCC), depending on what version of Dev-C++ you are using however, it is likley to be a very old version of GCC.

All that said, this is not a difference between compilers.  If you dereference an invalid pointer (one not initialised or assigned a valid address), then the subsequent behaviour is undefined.  "Undefined" includes the possibility that the behaviour will be different on different platforms, different compilers, different compiler options or even different executions on the same code on the same machine.

That is to say that in this case your code (preceding the line you posted) is at fault, not the compiler.  It is probably incorrect on both Linux and Windows, but the "undefined" behaviour is simply different as could be expected.

Comment: It could be packaged with a shiny new TDM-GCC build too. ;) http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Comment: @Orwell:  I am aware to that project, which is why I asked about the version.  I am guessing that this is your project?